# How to copy/move object of amazon s3 having multi level childs to destination?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I have to implement copy/move functionality of amazon s3 objects. but in case of objects with multilevel childs i am unable to copy/move all objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use S3DirectoryInfo.Move and S3DirectoryInfo.Copy methods see the examples below (AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3 Version 3.1.0.0):`enter code here`

```
AmazonS3Config cfg = new AmazonS3Config();
cfg.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;//bucket location
string bucketName = "source bucket";
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your accessKey", "your secretKey", cfg);

S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName, "sourceFolder");
 string bucketName2 = "destination butcket";               
    S3DirectoryInfo destination = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName2);
  source.CopyTo(destination); 
// or 
source.MoveTo(destination);
```

Probably it can help you.

Comment: thanx for your valuable response.

Comment: thanks Luis. from this one answer i get answers of many questions.

Answer (score 13):

If you are doing this in .Net Core, you won't have access to the DirectoryInfoClass (referenced in the answers above), as the Amazon.S3.IO namespace is not included in the AWS S3 SDK for .net core.

Instead copy and delete the objects as illustrated below:

```
    public async Task MoveObjectAsync(string srcBucket, string srcKey, string destBucket, string destKey)
    {
        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest
        {
            SourceBucket = srcBucket,
            SourceKey = srcKey,
            DestinationBucket = destBucket,
            DestinationKey = destKey                
        };
        CopyObjectResponse response = await _client.CopyObjectAsync(request);

        var request = new DeleteObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Key = srcKey
        };
        var response = await _client.DeleteObjectAsync(request);
    }
```

Comment: What will be the policy of S3 bucket for this? I'm not able to copy due to "Anonymous users cannot copy objects.  Please authenticate." error.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME);
            request.WithKey(PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.ProjectName.Replace("_", " ") + "/");
            request.WithTimeout(-1);
            request.WithReadWriteTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000);
            request.WithContentBody("");
            s3Client.PutObject(request);
            S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, BUCKET_NAME, PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.OldProjectName.Replace("_", " "));
            S3DirectoryInfo destination = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, BUCKET_NAME, PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.ProjectName.Replace("_", " "));
            source.CopyTo(destination);

            source.Delete(true);
```

Here once you copied from one to another first folder is getting deleted.